# ImageView in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

Im developing an Application.My requirement is to display the Image and String(Title and Subtitle). Image and String both are downloaded and parsed and then displayed.I am using `Hashmap<ImageView, String>`/Currently I am able to display Image in ListView but I dont know how to display the String according to Image.Please Help me If anyone is having logic.

Thank you.

Abhishek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to implement a custom `Adapter` for your `ListView`.

Check out [this example](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) as a starting point.